# Unable to build Pillow (Python Imaging Library) from source on Linux

Tags: python-imaging-library

I'm following the instructions for **Building From Source** at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#building-from-source for building on Debian Linux. Pillow seems to work fine on my system after I follow these steps, but it doesn't seem to be really building from source.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git
Cloning into 'Pillow'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 67869, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (163/163), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (95/95), done.
remote: Total 67869 (delta 90), reused 128 (delta 68), pack-reused 67706
Receiving objects: 100% (67869/67869), 83.17 MiB | 9.39 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (50202/50202), done.

$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools
[sudo] password for dan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.9.2-3).
python3-setuptools is already the newest version (52.0.0-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

Remove all the source files from libImaging directory to prove its not building from source:

```
$ cd Pillow
$ rm ./src/libImaging/*
```

Continue to follow the **Building From Source** instructions at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#building-from-source for Debian Linux:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home/dan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (22.3.1)

$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow --no-binary :all:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
DEPRECATION: --no-binary currently disables reading from the cache of locally built wheels. In the future --no-binary will not influence the wheel cache. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use the --no-cache-dir option. You can use the flag --use-feature=no-binary-enable-wheel-cache to test the upcoming behaviour. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11453
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-9.3.0.tar.gz (50.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  DEPRECATION: Pillow is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because the '--no-binary' option was enabled for it and this currently disables local wheel building for projects that don't have a 'pyproject.toml' file. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11451
  Running setup.py install for Pillow ... done
Successfully installed Pillow-9.3.0
```

Pillow works on my system, but as I removed a large number of source files, it doesn't appear that I'm really building from source. The output says *"Using cached Pillow-9.3.0.tar.gz"* which implies it isn't using what I cloned. I think I'm following the all directions. Did I do something wrong or are the directions incomplete?

Comment: I think you need to `cd Pillow/src` then `python3 -m pip install .`

Comment: Thanks Mark. I gave it a try, but it isn't happy:`$ cd Pillow/src`
`$ python3 -m pip install .`
`Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.'`

Comment: I'll see if I can find time to try on a debian docker image tomorrow.

Comment: It would be much appreciated. I'm trying to hack Pillow so it will support the `openjpeg` (JPEG 2000) `-PLT` option which currently Pillow doesn't support https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg-2000 . Of course I need to be able to build Pillow from source that contains my change and install that build to see if my hack will work.

Answer (score 0):

I built the latest Pillow from source inside a dockerized `debian:latest` like this:

```
# Start debian:latest docker
docker run -it debian:latest

# Install all the junk you need and upgrade pip
apt update && apt install git python3-dev python3-setuptools python3-pip cmake libjpeg-dev
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip  # this line MAY not be strictly necessary

# Clone PIL/Pillow from Github
git clone https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git

# Install from source
cd Pillow
python3 -m pip install .
```

Comment: OK, now if I `$ rm ./src/libImaging/*` the build fails (as it should), unlike when I follow the Building From Source instructions at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-from-source that don't seem to build from source. Let me see if I get get my changes to compile. I can then open an issue against the Pillow documentation and get this fixed.

Comment: Mark, my hack now seems to work. Thank you for solving my problem! I'll follow up with the Pillow team to correct their documentation.

Comment: I opened https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6755 to resolve this issue for others.